# Interpreting linear regression with NA for estimates

Tags: linear-model, interpretation, missing-data, predictor

I have 3 variables. Income is the dependent variable(continuous), sex(binomial), workhrs(categorical) i fitted a linear model and obtained the result:

My question is: Is this model usable? The NA values come from the fact that workhrs is missing 4 categories. The fifth one is i think due to coliniarity.
The adjusted R squared is pretty high, but is the model Usefull to predict? or the interaction is not useful and should be dropped?

```
Call:
lm(formula = income ~ factor(sex) + factor(workhrs) + factor(sex):factor(workhrs))

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-6.757 -1.261  0.000  1.531  5.690 

Coefficients: (5 not defined because of singularities)
                               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      31.330      4.645   6.744 8.42e-05 ***
factor(sex)1                      0.160      6.569   0.024 0.981101    
factor(workhrs)1                  2.930      5.689   0.515 0.618960    
factor(workhrs)2                 13.240      8.691   1.523 0.161968    
factor(workhrs)4                 10.935      5.689   1.922 0.086773 .  
factor(workhrs)5                  6.960      6.569   1.059 0.316997    
factor(workhrs)6                 30.045      8.691   3.457 0.007192 ** 
factor(workhrs)7                 18.315      5.689   3.219 0.010503 *  
factor(workhrs)8                 26.947      5.364   5.024 0.000715 ***
factor(workhrs)9                 25.340      6.569   3.857 0.003863 ** 
factor(workhrs)10                38.850      9.291   4.182 0.002370 ** 
factor(sex)1:factor(workhrs)1     9.160      8.691   1.054 0.319347    
factor(sex)1:factor(workhrs)2        NA         NA      NA       NA    
factor(sex)1:factor(workhrs)4     9.060      8.046   1.126 0.289276    
factor(sex)1:factor(workhrs)5    23.035      8.691   2.651 0.026451 *  
factor(sex)1:factor(workhrs)6        NA         NA      NA       NA    
factor(sex)1:factor(workhrs)7     3.325      8.691   0.383 0.710895    
factor(sex)1:factor(workhrs)8        NA         NA      NA       NA    
factor(sex)1:factor(workhrs)9        NA         NA      NA       NA    
factor(sex)1:factor(workhrs)10       NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.645 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9263,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8117 
F-statistic: 8.083 on 14 and 9 DF,  p-value: 0.001742
```

Answer (score 3):

> Residual standard error: 4.645 on 9 degrees of freedom

This means that you have only 9 more observations than number of parameters in the model. You would like to have a little more than that to have any hope for a sensible result. My rule of thumb is to have at least 20 observations per parameter to estimate when dealing with financial or economic data.

UPDATE: the NAs are a different but related issue. Most likely you did not have different sexes working 6 hours, so it can't estimate this interaction, and reports NA. If you had more observations, you would likely address issue too.

As a workaround, I'd suggest you introduce workhours as a continuous variable. This way the number of parameters would shrink very considerably. It may not be ideal situation, but you simply have not enough observations to estimate this model specification.

Comment: So this means that the model is not useful or not usable ?

Comment: Estimates are not usable. You need more observations to estimate your model specification.

Comment: If i would not take workhrs as categorical, wouldnt that change the model works? can you explain how the model changes in this case?

Comment: @Bob, of course it's a different model. A continuous work hours variable states that the relationship is linear, while categorical is free of such constraint, that's why it needs more data to estimate. You could play with a linear spline, e.g. introduce two variables MAX(wh,4) and MIN(wh,4), then you'll have two slopes for high and low work hours. It's like in between the linear model and your categorical.